# Добросердечие / Добросердечность

Tags: семантика

Будьте добры подсказать: есть ли разница? (кроме того, что первое - устаревшая форма)
И как будет выглядеть прилагательное от добросердечия (добросердечивое)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По  употреблению эти слова различаются и не всегда взаимозаменяемы. Добросердечность имеет более широкий смысл и может относиться не только напрямую к человеческим качествам, но и к их косвенным проявлениям. Например, можно говорить о "добросердечности обстановки", и это будет означать, что такой по свойствам её сделали люди, проявившие своё добросердечие или добросердечность (к людям можно отнести и то, и другое). Но приложить этим же способом "добросердечие" к свойствам обстановки вряд ли стилистически возможно: это чисто человеческое качество. В контексте "обстановки" можно данное слово иначе употребить: "в обстановке добросердечия (участников встречи)" - здесь нет странного "добросердечия обстановки". "Добросердечие" буквально означает, что у человека "доброе сердце", а "добросердечность" имеет к этому опосредованное отношение: добросердечие (его доброе сердце) -> добросердечный (соответственно, он такой) -> добросердечность (то, какой он, проявляется в этом).

**P.S.** Есть и другие пары понятий, различающихся по употреблению как прямое выражение свойства и как перенесённое на сущность, которой оно изначально может быть и не свойственно. Например:

реальность (событий) - реалистичность (планов)

просторечие (форма выражения) - просторечность (текста, в котором много просторечий)

косноязычие (субъекта) - косноязычность (его речи)

Answer (score 1):

Эти синонимы. По поводу прилагательного: добросердечный, добросердечная, добросердечные

Comment: @N3ver_Again, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).